# dplyr::mutate multiple functions on one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure out how to mutate a single column of data by several functions using dplyr. I can do every column:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(min, max))
```

But I don't know how to select one column. I can imagine something like this though this obviously does not run:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Length, funs(min, max))
```

I can sort of accomplish this task using `do()` and a custom function like this:

```
summary_func = function(x){
  tibble(max_out = max(x),
         min_out = min(x)
  )
}


iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(summary_func(.$Sepal.Length))
```

However this doesn't really do what I want to do either because it isn't adding to the exist tibble a la `mutate`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `mutate_at`

```
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>%
   mutate_at("Sepal.Length", funs(min, max))
```

It takes a `character` so watch the quotes

Comment: You could also use `mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Length), funs(min, max))` rather than using quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Use `mutate`

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(min = min(Sepal.Length),
         max = max(Sepal.Length))
```